Inconsistency between g++ and clang++ on template parameter pack deduction
I found the following minimal example when experimenting metaprogramming:
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <size_t ...Is>
void print(const std::tuple<std::index_sequence<Is>...>&) {
    ((std::cout << Is << "  "), ...);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    print(std::make_tuple(std::index_sequence<3>{}, std::index_sequence<1>{}));
    return 0;
}

I thought there's no ambiguity in deducing Is to be [3,1], and the code indeed compiles with g++. However, clang++ gives the following error message:
hw.cpp:23:5: error: no matching function for call to 'print'
    print(std::make_tuple(std::index_sequence<3>{}, std::index_sequence<1>{}));
    ^~~~~
hw.cpp:17:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting values for parameter 'Is' (<3UL> vs. <1UL>)
void print(const std::tuple<std::index_sequence<Is>...>&) {
     ^
1 error generated.

My system is WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I've tried two clang++ compilers, Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1 and Ubuntu clang version 15.0.7, both of which are installed via apt and emitted the same message.
I'm just wondering, under the c++ standard, is it a clang bug or a gnu extension?
